# How to set private member of javascript object

Tags: javascript

I have a dog class that contains private members with public methods to access these members using closure.

```
class Dog {

constructor(name,  age,  avail) {

    var _name, _age, _availability;

    _name = name;
    _age = age;
    _availability = avail;

    this.getName = function () {
        return _name;
    }

    this.getAge = function () {
        return _age;
    }

    this.getAvailability = function () {
        return _availability;
    }

}

Dogs[0] = new Dog("Macy","6 Years", true);
```

I want to be able to change the able to change the _availability member.
I tried adding:

```
        this.setAvailbility = function (param) {
        if (param == "false") {
            _availability = false;
        } else if (param == "true") {
            _availability = true;
        }
```

but that didn't work.  How can I go about doing this?

```js
class Dog {

  constructor(name, age, avail) {

    var _name, _age, _availability;

    _name = name;
    _age = age;
    _availability = avail;

    this.getName = function() {
      return _name;
    }

    this.getAge = function() {
      return _age;
    }

    this.getAvailability = function() {
      return _availability;
    }
    this.setAvailbility = function(param) {
      if (param == "false") {
        _availability = false;
      } else if (param == "true") {
        _availability = true;
      }
    }

  }
}

var dog = new Dog("Macy", "6 Years", true);
dog.setAvailbility("false");
console.log(dog.getAvailability())
```

Comment: @AmardeepBhowmick he wants to use getter / setter methods.

Comment: I've added a snippet to the question merging the two snippets you have posted. The code seems to work just fine. Please verify your code and [edit] the question with more details if it still doesn't work for you.

Comment: Note that you have `setAvailbility` instead of `setAvail[a]bility`, which seems to be a typo, but you have it in both places in your question so the code works. Perhaps your real code isn't working because you have the typo in one place, but not the other.

Comment: @Paulpro thank you so much. Can't believe I didn't catch that. Think I need to take a break haha

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a setter method `setAvailability(avail)` like this:

```js
class Dog {
  _name;
  _age;
  _availability;

  constructor(name, age, avail) {
    this._name = name;
    this._age = age;
    this._availability = avail;
  }
  
  getName() {
    return this._name;
  }

  getAge() {
    return this._age;
  }

  getAvailability() {
    return this._availability;
  }
  
  setAvailability(avail) {
    this._availability = avail;
  }
}

const dog = new Dog("Macy", "6 Years", true);

console.log('Name:', dog.getName());
console.log('Age:', dog.getAge());
console.log('Availability:', dog.getAvailability());

dog.setAvailability(false);

console.log('Updated availability:', dog.getAvailability());
```